# How to embed Landbot to Next.js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm not sure how to embed Landbot to my Next.js app, I tried to override _document.js and add this to the body, but there is no effect...

[image: Landbot]

Answer (score 0):

I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/landbot-next-04opl?file=/pages/index.js) showing an example of landbot embed in a Next.js Application, using `next/script`.

First of all, create a script:

```
import Script from "next/script";

<Script
  strategy="lazyOnload"
  src="https://static.landbot.io/landbot-3/landbot-3.0.0.js"
  onLoad={setupLandbot}
/>
```

Implement setupLandbot function:

```
function setupLandbot() {
  new Landbot.Livechat({
    configUrl: "https://chats.yexir.com/v3/H-10503-NYE2UEZ0OZYFHRU9/index.json"
  });
}
```

I hope it helped!